# Updating Miniconda's Python to 3.9.x, but Miniconda is installed with Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, homebrew, miniconda

I have installed miniconda on my machine using Homebrew (`homebrew install --cask miniconda`). Homebrew uses the following installer:

```
❯ brew info miniconda | rg miniconda:
miniconda: py38_4.9.2 (auto_updates)
```

i.e. with the following python version:

```
❯ conda info | rg "python version"
         python version : 3.8.10.final.0
```

However, the official Miniconda installation page displays a newer version, which is shipped with Python 3.9. I guess I have three alternatives:

1. Manually download the newer Miniconda installation.
2. Wait for the [Homebrew Cask Formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/miniconda.rb) to be upgraded (how do I point it out to them?)

But wouldn't this delete my environments and the packages I have installed? Or can I just copy them to the new Miniconda lib/cache? Or can I upgrade Python directly from within Miniconda?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or can I upgrade Python directly from within Miniconda?

Yes, it is as simple as

```
conda install python=3.9
```

Comment: Well, that was easy! This solves the problem I had with `pyenv` too: I do not actually need to install each new conda version, but simply update it from conda itself.